# Heroku - Application Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've created simple application with Ruby on Rails and I’ve tried to commit it on Heroku. I’ve followed this [Getting Started on Heroku guide](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart),
I finished it and try to open my page but I still see an Error:
Application Error:

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Anybody know how to deal with it?

---

I don’t know what was happen but I’ve done this step, unfortunately I have another problem, I run a few commands:

> # **git add .**
>    # **git commit -m "my commit"**
>   On branch master nothing to commit (working directory clean)
>    # **git push heroku
>   master** Everything up-to-date
>    # **heroku open** Opening
>   http ://eerie-meadow-9207.heroku.com/
>    # **heroku restart**
>   Restarting processes... done
>    # **heroku open** Opening
>   http ://eerie-meadow-9207.heroku.com/

And I see a message:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.

From `heroku logs` *[timestamps removed for clarity]*:

```
app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 77.236.11.34 at 2011-10-31 11:50:38 -0700
app[web.1]:   Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
heroku[router]: GET eerie-meadow-9207.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=728
heroku[nginx]: 77.236.11.34 - - [31/Oct/2011:11:50:38 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.9.2.23) Gecko/20110921 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.23" eerie-meadow-9207.heroku.com
app[web.1]:
heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to bouncing
heroku[web.1]: State changed from bouncing to created
heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 40376 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
heroku[web.1]: Process exited
app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024 
app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:40376, CTRL+C to stop
app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 77.236.11.34 at 2011-10-31 11:50:59-0700
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:   Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  relation "products" does not exist
app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
app[web.1]:         ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"products"'::regclass
app[web.1]:           AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
app[web.1]: ):
app[web.1]:   app/controllers/store_controller.rb:3:in `index'
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
heroku[router]: GET eerie-meadow-9207.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=81ms status=500 bytes=728
heroku[nginx]: 77.236.11.34 - - [31/Oct/2011:11:50:59 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.9.2.23) Gecko/20110921 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.23" eerie-meadow-9207.heroku.com
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 77.236.11.34 at 2011-10-31 11:54:00-0700
app[web.1]:   Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
```

I cannot understand it because on my netbook it works on localhost, any ideas?

Comment: one solution: `heroku logs` in console to know what happened

Comment: what stack did you use? 'heroku stack' and which rails version?

Comment: This could be any number of things.  Have you looked in the logs or checked your code is what you meant to type in against the tutorial?

Comment: HEROKU LOGS:


2011-10-31T13:07:19+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET eerie-meadow-9207.heroku.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2011-10-31T13:07:19+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 77.236.11.34 - - [31/Oct/2011:06:07:19 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 607 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.9.2.23) Gecko/20110921 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.23" eerie-meadow-9207.heroku.com
2011-10-31T13:07:24+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET eerie-meadow-9207.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: HEROKU STACK:


  aspen-mri-1.8.6
* bamboo-mri-1.9.2
  bamboo-ree-1.8.7
  cedar (beta)

Comment: This LOGS just show what was happen after run command HEROKU OPEN. Here you've got all logs: http://www.scribd.com/doc/71012505/Logs-Error

Comment: ok - resolved, but now I have another problem - I've edited my post

Comment: @apneadiving, "one solution: heroku logs...", And what? How the knowledge of what happen can solve the problem? Logs doesn't show the solution. Only the problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the time heroku issues are due to lack of privileges to access file system. In order for your application to work on heroku you must make sure it wont try to write anything to disk (but in temporary folder).

The typical example is js/css compiling process, e.g. with compass, for which you will find a solution on their knowledge database: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-compass

You should look further in the heroku logs see if there is any "permission denied" issue at application startup or during the first requests.

Comment: ok - resolved, but now, I have another problem - I've edited my post

Comment: Thanks. Configuring compass to work with Heroku worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

Try using the command

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: This returned for me the syntax error, i was missing. Thanks for this hint. I never would have guessed right from the heroku logs command.

Comment: I had a similar error, example.com/users was giving the same html output while on this step of railstutorial.org : https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app#sec-demo_users_resource and using `heroku run rake db:migrate` solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Try restarting your app with `heroku restart`. Assuming your app runs fine locally, this should do the trick. It solved the issue for me as I only refactored the schema and the db:reset did not seem to do the trick.

Comment: I run my application locally and it works. Heroku restart gave: Restarting processes... done, nextly heroku open and I see this same error...  I read that could be a problem if you use many times command HEROKU CREATE. I created around 6-7 projects but I've deleted all this project from HEROKU site. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check out the video in my answer. There's a lack of resources on uploading 3.1 apps to heroku for the first time, but the video guides you through reading and solving the errors.

Comment: This worked for me. I had left the app asleep for some time, since nothing was changed I was confused as to why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_3dIPgXgkg

If you already have your application built, go to the point in the video when he begins pushing the sample app to heroku. Unfortunately heroku returns hard to solve errors when uploading 3.1 apps for the first time. Follow the troubleshooting steps in the video and you'll be fine.

Comment: I would try `heroku db:reset` then `heroku db:migrate` If these set of commands don't work, try `heroku destroy` and redeploy with the youtube tutorial troubleshooting methods

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when I was starting to create a discord bot and make it online. And I figured out the reason for this was using the node latest current version(v17.1), I wasted about 2 days for this and tried downgrading node version to v16.7.And to my surprise it worked!.

**So I recommend downgrading to v16.7 or the latest LTS version when you are checking this and do install the current latest version
https://nodejs.org/ca/blog/release/v16.7.0/**

Here's the full code

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
// WShen the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
const http = require('http');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Bot is up and running');
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(PORT);
  setInterval(function() {
    http.get("http://<your app name>.herokuapp.com");
}, 300000); // every 5 minutes (300000)
```

Note:Last 3 lines of this code is completely additional and what they do is stop heroku from putting app to sleep every 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Have a look at your Procfile and check if you have added the proper command in it such as `web: python run.py`. I wasn't able to connect then I placed the command `heroku logs --tail` to see what was the problem and I saw that within my Procfile I had a type mistake such as >>>`web: oython run.py`<<< making the app not work. So, pay attention to it. command: $`echo web: python run.py > Procfile`

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that in the data base, you have allowed "any IP Address" to connect. This is called whitelisting the IP Address. Example: 0.0.0/0. This is because Heroku, each time it spins up, uses a different IP address. But you can change it later using Heroku docs and the docs of your Database service provider.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud2VJ.png

You can use this image as an example which is a screenshot of MongoDB Atlas

Answer (score 0):

Before you start please allow access to your DB network from anywhere.

Well I have also faced this "Application error" problem once
that time I used these command lines

1. git init
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "my first commit"
4. heroku create YourAppName
5. git push heroku main

But as you know I got the "Application error"

Then I used these commands

1. heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "my first commit"
4. git push heroku main

After that "Application error" problem was solved.
Well, I'm not sure if it works for you or not but I guess you can try at least.